# Prefix or rename Spring Environment properties

Tags: spring, properties-file

I have several properties files, one of them is an contains the `accessId` and `secretKey` for amazon Aws. I currently import them using `<context:property-placeholder>`.

The problem is that I don't really want properties like `accessId` and `secretKey` since Spring properties are global (they are reachable and rewritable anywhere). For example, I can use another service in addition to AWS that will also use `accessId` and `secretKey` for access, and the properties will end up written over.

How do I prefix the properties upon import? Ideally, I want to access them as `aws.accessId`. Then, even though it's still global, there is less room for error.

Comment: Is it not possible to simply call the properties aws.accessId and aws.secretKey in your properties file? Then you would not have to prefix or rename them.

Comment: It's possible, but I don't want to. It seems unclean to prefix all properties inside a file with `aws.`